# Elasticsearch: query accuracy

Tags: elasticsearch

Reading that the elasticsearch may not have a complete accuracy for term aggregation when setting the size ([link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)), I start questioning this: are the normal queries (without aggregations) accurate when setting `from` and `size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the things are a little different [see official explanation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html)

Comment: What is the impact on the query accuracy? as stated above, it extracts a subset of the results computed, and discards the remains.

Answer (score 1):

`from` and `size` parameters are only related to the pagination of your results.

They have no impact on the results accuracy : it's just extracting a subset of the results computed for the request.